Restrict Block from having a Parent or Ancenstor Block
I have a "custom/section" block with a template of "allowedBlocks" innerblocks eg. { children }.
But have been unable to restrict the "custom/section" block from having a Parent block.

I've tried the following settings in the "custom/section" block.json metadata.
{ "parent":[], "ancestor":[] }
//
{ "parent":[""], "ancestor":[""] }
//
{ "parent":["core/post-content"], "ancestor":["core/post-content"] }

This restricts insertion but does not restrict the block from being wrapped in a core/group via the editor ⋮ block settings.
Multiple instances of the "custom/section" block are allowed so contentOnly lock isn't appropriate.
references:

gutenberg/issues/7845
stackoverflow: how-to-exclude-parent-block-from-group-columns-innerblocks




what's the reason for restricting the parent block? Keep in mind that in a block theme there will always be a parent block and you'll have no control over what it will be, likewise with a reusable block/synced pattern. There might be ways to mitigate this in some circumstances but it depends on why you need this and your circumstance

Thanks @TomJNowell - Appreciate you taking an interest. Your reputation precedes you. This project and question does not align with the ideals of the FSE experience. Since posting, I have located documentation related to the isGroupable() && isUngroupable() methods and am exploring the viability of long term use.

I did not see the screenshot at the end, it is still possible to drag and drop your sections into other blocks. isGroupable is not the solution you're hoping for, it's a registry selector you can't modify not a parameter you can set. This looks like an x y problem, what's the actual issue that you're hoping to solve by controlling parents, why do you want to prevent grouping?

We're working with a highly defined tree-like data structure. The -current- block is a mid level branch node with children. A list block and list-items is a nice structural analogy. A make.wp article on ungroup transform and variations gave me some hope the param might b nullable. Am starting to believe we need to find a solution which works with rather than against WP

hmmm some research suggests you might be able to do this by unregistering the group block, note that the editor will immediatley crash if any group blocks are present. It is possible to set the block that the editor considers the "grouping" block to something else

otherwise, to play nicely perhaps there's another way of looking at it, e.g. have you ever used a Jupyter notebook? Currently every block in the document is "significant", but in code some lines are just comments, or "dressing/annotation", perhaps the code could treat group blocks the same and filter them out before it gets used? Or group blocks could be filtered on render to remove the tags and only show their children so they'd never appear in final HTML output. Or strip them out on save? Keeping them but nullifying their effect would let you use them to organise things

Thank you again for your attention to this issue. Unregistering the group is a fantastic example of why I'm looking for an answer to the wrong solution. Im unfamiliar the Jupyter notebook, but your reference to 'significant' blocks, brings to mind the core/post-template, which may not have been your intent. but does offer us a new methods to explore. Thanks :)
